# Is there a way to monitor next.js apollo client requests?

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, apollo-client, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a next.js website that works with apollo client to make request to an apollo server, the server 's OS is Windows Server 2012 R2 and the page is working with a reverse proxy on IIS. The next.js website and the apollo server are running as Windows services.

The problem is that sometimes the requests are dropped randomly and i don't know why. I was looking for errors in the apollo server logs but it doesn't appear there, so the request doesn't even reach the server.

Currently the page is in the web and the clients are telling that when they make a request the page, it returns a server error randomly. I tried to replicate the error making several requests but unfortunately i don't get it because all is fine here.

Is there a way monitor the page requests and find why are dropped?

Comment: Have you run tests locally?

Comment: "it returns a server error randomly" - what error does it return?

Comment: You can take a look at: https://superuser.com/questions/357123/how-can-i-monitor-all-the-outgoing-http-requests-from-my-pc

Comment: The issue is that i do not know the exact error, because im not getting it on my computer. The clients say that it is a server error but they do not specify. As i said before those requests are not getting to the server because the errors are not showing up in the logs.

Comment: You can use the failed request tracing feature on IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that i don't need to track apollo client requests, i need to track user errors. So sentry.io can do the work and it works fine. It was a session error, because some clients got invalid tokens.